# How to disable Git information (Inlay Hints) in editor in Android Studio Electric Eel?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've updated to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 and cannot find the option to disable git info from editor.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

I find it distracting and annoying.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Go to Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Code Vision -> Uncheck Code Author.

Names will get disappear.

OR

Right click on any name and it will show option *Hide 'Code Vision: Code Author' Inlay Hints.*

Comment: This does not remove the Git Log author, displayed above classes in Electric Eel, unfortunately.

Comment: trying upgrading the version, it works in Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 4

Comment: @straya this solution worked for me - I just had to invalidate caches/restart after hitting apply in preferences. Give that a shot!

Answer (score 7):

Remove "code author" option

[image]