# How to disable github username references inside files in android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I don't know exactly why but my android studio started displaying above the signature of the class and methods the github username of the person who made changes to that class/method. When clicking on these highlighted items, the git blame tab opens on the left side.
I want to disable the appearance of these labels in the code.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111205/8003058) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In macOS, as of Android Hedgehog, go to

**Preferences > Editor > Inlay Hints > Code Vision > Code author**

[image]